# Better performance between frontend JS and backend JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am a frontend guy, but I am working on a project in which I need to process lots of data in my nodeJS backend (my front is reactJS).

But once the data that needed to be processed in the backend is processed, I have the choice of either reprocessing this data in node or in react (knowing that in the end, I need this data in frontend).

Example: An array of links has been created in my backend, but I need to extract a single link from this array, in order to display it in React. I have the choice, pass the array to react and process the data there, or do it directly in node.

Is there a common fashion to fix this dilemma? What should I take into account to make a decision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not good to send excessive information from your backend to your frontend. If you're going to send data to your frontend from your back-end and a lot of it isn't going to be used, then it's probably best to adjust your backend so that it only returns information that's going to be actually used by your frontend.

Alternatively, if your frontend isn't going to use all the the information sent by your backend right away, but potentially might use it later (based on user input), then it's better to send all the data from your backend and process it on the front end as needed to avoid making future requests to your backend.

Taking an array of links as an example:

If the user requests to see a link based on certain criteria, and that's the only link that they are going to see (based on the design of your application), then your backend should process that request and return only the link that your user wants to see to be displayed on the front end.

If the user can request to see a link, but could potentially request to see another link later, then your backend should send a full array of links that might need to be displayed at some point. Then your frontend can display the links at the appropriate time without having to make a request to your backend each time the user wants to see a new link.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, if the logic doesn’t need to be done by the browser, then do it on the server. It will help you with reducing the size of your app in the long run. You want your final, bundled .js file to be as small as possible. That’s just one small step you can take to contribute to that.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it all depends on your business logic. Regarding how best to handle an array of items to be sent from backend to front-end, if a user will only ever need to see this one item, for example, then by all means, have the backend parse the array of data on its end and send that single item to the client front-end. If, on the other hand, you anticipate that you'll need to work with an array of items to be presented to the user at some point in the app, it would be reasonable to simply have the backend send the array of items. Furthermore, that array of items could be, for instance, a filtered version of the items that would be relevant to this particular user.